# Parse words out of a string

Tags: c#

I need to parse a string from `NHRM__Location__c` to just `Location`.  I feel really dumb because this is not my first rodeo.  I do not want to add the code in an array.  `NHRM` is a namespace that may change depending on who's using it so at some point that will be a key in the app.config file.

I was thinking of just splitting the string on `__` and then loading the rest of the word into a character array and trimming that guy down but I feel like I may be waaaay over complicating things.

Comment: "This maybe a duplicate and if so feel free to close." Does this mean you didn't try to look up an answer before you posted this?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx

Comment: if you can guarantee the `__`, why not just `str.Split("__")[1]`

Comment: @dfundako I tried to lookup the answer yes.  I did not find a duplicate I did find a bunch of arrays and answers I was not looking for.   I can make the list out of answers if you would like to view it.  I'm not a noob looking for you to do my work I just need a quick brain refresher and I'm not coming up with what I'm looking for.

Comment: In fairness to Nicole, I've asked questions on SO after spending an exhaustive hour searching for duplicates, only to have a question closed as a duplicate.  It's just something that happens, and I interpreted Nicole's last line as simply being sensitive to that, rather than an admission of no effort.

Comment: @AMy thank you Amy its been a long day.  Kind regards!

Comment: @NicolePhillips Please mark an answer as accepted so that this question will be seen as answered.

Comment: @NicolePhillips Please mark an answer as accepted so that this question will be seen as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
string sample = "NHRM__Location__c";
Console.WriteLine(sample.Split('_')[2]);
```

Comment: The input has two underscores in a row, you are splitting on a single underscore.  I think when you split you will find the word in the [2] position is the one with the word "Location", not the [1] position.  Also, the method is 'Split', not 'split'

Comment: Thanks for that yes it was location 2 I feel really dumb. I will accept the answer shortly after a meeting.  Kind regards on the refresher.

Answer (score 3):

I have put this into a [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) for you using this code:

```
using System;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string stringToSplit = "NHRM__Location__c"; // 2 underscores in each location
        char[] sep = new char[] {'_', '_'};
        string newString = stringToSplit.Split(sep)[2];

        Console.WriteLine(newString);
    }
}
```

I know this is similar to the 1st answer, but I just wanted to prove that `[2]` does work, well at least for me in .Net Fiddle.

I hope this helps!

**Update**

> System.String
>
> Return Value - An array whose elements contain the substrings from this instance that are delimited by one or more characters in separator

So if I were to change the code to `[4]` then it would return just `c`.. and `[0]` would return `NHRM`.. the array values do not include the separator

Comment: Your stringToSplit variable is not the same as the OP's.

Comment: well it works because your input is different than what OP has

Comment: The original input string had two underscores in a row.  Yours only has one.

Comment: @aaaabbbb Updated

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Thanks for the update to two underscores.  Now please update the note that follows the code that says "[1] does work"